# JSON Field, read from CSV, and detect values that do not have a curly bracket at the end

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pyspark

I have a JSON field in a CSV file that has good and bad values.

Bad values look like (note: missing end curly bracket):

```
"{'Id': '1', 'fruit': ['banana', 'grape', 'orange'], 'business': ""Publix""
```

vs

Good values look like:

```
{'Id': '3', 'fruit': ['peach', 'orange'], 'business': 'Aldi}
```

I need to identify all the rows that are missing curly brackets in this JSON field using PySpark.

How can I read this problematic JSON field and create a new field with the last value of ea. bad value? So for example, using Example 1:

```
Last Value
""Publix""
```

What I've tried:

```
df.withColumn("col1", F.to_json(F.col("col1")))\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Which gives me an error: `cannot resolve 'to_json(`col1`)' due to data type mismatch: Input type string must be a struct, array of structs or a map or array of map.;;`

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question.

Given the bad JSON file, you want to at import, format as CSV, but then do the following:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("escape", '"').load("etc.csv")
```

Hope this helps someone out there! :)

Edit: option("escape", '"') is the trick.